# Passing props to specific nested children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to configure some props to children.

In this dummy example I am testing the function in order to specifically target any child, nested or not, with the following prop : `swipeMe`.

It works very well if inside my `div` on the `render function` if it contains just a single child, like this:

```
    <SwapableItems>
      <div>
        {/*the p element will get the red color as defined on childrenHandler*/}
        <p swipeMe>Add Props</p> 
      </div>
    </SwapableItems>
```

Yet, if I add more children into my `div`, somehow I guess that my ternary operation on `childrenHandler` is not working well and I do not know why...

- If it has children, clone this element and call `childrenHandler` passing its children.
- If it has my desired prop, clone de element and do something with it.
- If none of the above, just clone the element.

```
return childHasChildren
      ? React.cloneElement(child, {}, childHasChildren)
      : child.props.swipeMe
      ? React.cloneElement(child, { ...swipeMeProps })
      : React.cloneElement(child, {});
```

Below is the full script.
You can also check it out on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sutherland-mvhqu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <SwapableItems>
      <div>
        <p swipeMe>Add Props</p>
        <div>Don't Add Props</div>
      </div>
    </SwapableItems>
  );
}

function SwapableItems({ children }) {
  const content = childrenHandler(children, { style: { color: "red" } });
  return content;
}

const childrenHandler = (children, swipeMeProps) => {
  const childEls = React.Children.toArray(children).map((child) => {
    const childHasChildren =
      child.props.children && React.isValidElement(child.props.children)
        ? childrenHandler(child.props.children, swipeMeProps)
        : undefined;
    return childHasChildren
      ? React.cloneElement(child, {}, childHasChildren)
      : child.props.swipeMe
      ? React.cloneElement(child, { ...swipeMeProps })
      : React.cloneElement(child, {});
  });
  return childEls;
};
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this work.
I wrapped nested children by SwapableItems if has children.

```js
function SwapableItems({ children }) {
  const props = { style: { color: "red" } };
  return Children.map(children, (child) => {
    let nestedChild = child.props.children;
    const hasNestedChild = nestedChild && typeof nestedChild !== "string"

    if (hasNestedChild) {
      nestedChild = <SwapableItems>{nestedChild}</SwapableItems>;
    }

    return child.props?.swipeMe || hasNestedChild
      ? cloneElement(child, child.props?.swipeMe ? props : {}, [nestedChild])
      : child;
  });
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-snow-8zm6u?file=/src/App.js:345-751

Comment: hey! I have checked your solution at this codesandBox and it did not work for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-minsky-xctve?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. could you please check? The desired behaviour is what I have just posted. Could you please check your answer on the link I've sent you? I have never seen this ```map``` syntax before, neither never thought of passing the whole component recursively. This would re-run the whole component, right?

Comment: I Fixed that https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-snow-8zm6u

Comment: > This would re-run the whole component, right?
No matter, because it is just a logical component and nothing will render to DOM.

Comment: But the benefit of that is, you could use hooks in every nested child, so maybe your state change will have better performance.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The issue is that it does clone all the elements. I all looking for a solution that will clone only the elements that have the specific prop.

Comment: I have updated the solution and now just if needed to clone elements it will be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

`child.props.children` is an array, so `React.isValidElement(child.props.children)` is always falsy, to fix it try using `React.cloneElement` on it:

```
React.isValidElement(React.cloneElement(child.props.children)); // true
```

A style reset example:

```
const styleA = {
  color: "blue"
};

const InlineReset = ({ children }) => {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    console.log(child.props);

    return React.cloneElement(child.props.children, { style: null });
  });
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <InlineReset>
      <div>
        <h1 style={styleA}>Hello </h1>
      </div>
    </InlineReset>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Child Children]

Comment: Hello, Dennis. I wanna pass elements with two children as props.children. So that is why I am looking for a deeper nesting solution. Your solution would not require any recursion at all. I have named this component in a wrong way. Let's call it ```<SwipableItems>```. I wanna pass data inside of it like this, in order to have one or more children: ```<Wrapper><Message swipeMe>My message<Message /> <HiddenStuff>Hidden under the Message<HiddenStuff/><Wrapper />```

Comment: So the problem is with `React.isValidElement(child.props.children)`, change the recursion function to accept a single element

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong in triggering the recursion in case the element being passed has children and that those children must be elements. I guess that I what I meant when I added ```React.isValidElement(child.props.children)```. Could you kindly explain what do you mean by just accepting a single child? Note that I may pass a list of children, all of them wrapping two children inside.

Comment: I want to ```map``` those wrappers, then check each of those wrapper's ```children```, then add ```props``` to any of them according to the config, in this case, if one of them has ```swipeMe``` as a ```prop```.

Comment: In your condition `React.isValidElement(child.props.children)` is always falsy

Comment: oh yes =) It is an array... So I must check if every child is a valid element =) I will fix it and check

Comment: Check updated answer, try using `cloneElement` on it

Comment: on your new solution you are adding props to all children, there is no way of targeting a child and if you add another child next to the <h1> tag you'll get an error

Comment: It's just an example,

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

I have initialized a `variable` which will hold the `recursion` outside of the logic and undefined.

`let childHasChildren;`

I have encapsulated the code inside an `if` statement with some adaptions:
"in case `child` has children, either an `array` or `object`, and if within the passed `children` there is/are valid `React` elements"

```
const deeperChildren = child.props.children;
    const arrayOfChildren = Array.isArray(deeperChildren);
    const singleChildren =
      typeof deeperChildren === "object" && deeperChildren !== null;
    if (
      (arrayOfChildren &&
        deeperChildren.some((c) => React.isValidElement(c))) ||
      (singleChildren && React.isValidElement(deeperChildren))
    ) {
```

In order to pass the recursion without errors, in case the code within the `if` statement is called, I have cloned a filter/single object of which children would be React valid elements, then I pass just these/this into the recursion:

```
const validChildren = arrayOfChildren
        ? deeperChildren.filter((c) => React.isValidElement(c))
        : deeperChildren;
```

Here is the [result](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-sutherland-mvhqu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Now it accepts, one item with children, or an Array. This can be configured in order to dynamically pass props, with default ones and other props that could be passed from outside of the component, although the latter is not my case. This solution was desired in order to achieve more complex stuff without using those solutions, such as render `props`, props contracts, HOCs, etc.

```
const childrenHandler = (children, swipeMeProps) => {
  const childEls = React.Children.toArray(children).map((child) => {
    let childHasChildren;
    const deeperChildren = child.props.children;
    const arrayOfChildren = Array.isArray(deeperChildren);
    const singleChildren =
      typeof deeperChildren === "object" && deeperChildren !== null;
    if (
      (arrayOfChildren &&
        deeperChildren.some((c) => React.isValidElement(c))) ||
      (singleChildren && React.isValidElement(deeperChildren))
    ) {
      const validChildren = arrayOfChildren
        ? deeperChildren.filter((c) => React.isValidElement(c))
        : deeperChildren;

      childHasChildren = childrenHandler(validChildren, swipeMeProps);
    }

    return childHasChildren
      ? React.cloneElement(child, {}, childHasChildren)
      : child.props.swipeMe
      ? React.cloneElement(child, { ...swipeMeProps })
      : React.cloneElement(child, {});
  });
  return childEls;
};
```